# piecewise function expectation with variable piecewise PDF

Tags: calculus, probability, expectation

I'm trying to compute expectation of a piecewise function which it's random variable is a piecewise function too! Problem is that limits of each piece  is variable.

Intractability of integrand is not important for now, but just how to define limits of this integral. Making long statement short, problem formulation is:
$$E\{G(r)\}=?$$
where 
$$G(r) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{A}{r^v},  & \text{if $\; r\le R_{th-1} \; $ } \\[2ex]
\frac{1}{r^v}\times10^{-1.2(\frac{-\tan^{-1}(\frac{H}{r})+\beta}{\theta_{3dB}})^2}, & \text{if $R_{th-1} \le r<R_{th-2}$ } \\ \\
\frac{A}{r^v},  & \text{if $\; R_{th-2}\le r \; $ } \\[2ex]
\end{cases}$$
and $H,\beta,\theta_{3dB},A$ all are known constants. $v \in \mathbb R^+$ is a known number. On the other hand $R_{th-1},R_{th-2}$ are unknwown and the only thing that we know is that $R_{th-1}<R_{th-2}$.

PDF of $r$ also is
 $$f_r(x)=
\begin{cases}
0, &\text{if $\; x<\frac{d\sqrt3}{2}\;$} \\
\frac{4x}{\sqrt{3}d^2}\cos^{-1}(\frac{d\sqrt3}{2x}), & \text{if $\; \frac{d\sqrt3}{2} \le x < d$} \\
\frac{\pi x}{\sqrt3 d^2}-\frac{2x}{\sqrt{3}d^2}\cos^{-1}(\frac{d\sqrt3}{2x}), &
\text{if $\; d \le x < \sqrt3 d$} \\
\frac{\pi x}{3\sqrt3 d^2}-\frac{2x}{\sqrt{3}d^2}\cos^{-1}(\frac{d\sqrt3}{x}), &
\text{if $\; \sqrt3d \le x < 2 d$} \\
0, & x>2d
\end{cases}$$
where $d$ is another known constant.

## -#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-

Update:
the result of above expectation is going to be used in an optimization problem.
Consider $R_{th-1}=\frac{H}{\tan(\beta+\theta \sqrt{\frac{S_{ll}}{12}})}$ and $R_{th-2}=\frac{H}{\tan(\beta-\theta \sqrt{\frac{S_{ll}}{12}})}$.
We assume that $\beta-\theta \sqrt{\frac{S_{ll}}{12}}>0 $.

$S_{ll}=20 $ is side lobe level and is a constant.

So indeed $\beta$ is not constant and is variable but for a given value of $\beta$ all the above mentioned variables are constant. We can do a grid search on the interval of $\beta$ to find the optimal value $\beta^{opt}$ but to do so, for each value of $\beta$ the expectation must be evaluated and be substituted in objective function.

Any HELP is appreciated, literally.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. How are you supposed to evaluate $G$ without knowing these bracketing values of $R$?

Comment: These values of R are going to be optimization variables in next stage. but we need to evaluate this expectation in the objective function first. all of this can be done numerically. but i need an expression for expectation to express objective function.

Comment: Do you mean an explicit function? You're not likely to find one. You'll need your objective function to be a "black box" function that takes the values of $R$ and numerically computes the expectation (which is at least straightforward to do, given your PDF for $r$).

Comment: sorry Ian. I'm gonna express the problem in more realistic way. indeed R's are function of another variable. I'll explain it to you as and edit, dude.

Comment: OK, so the whole thing is a function of $\beta$. But for a given value of $\beta$ this is just an ordinary integration, which you should almost certainly do numerically.

Comment: Yes Sir, indeed.

Comment: So where is the need for help? Are you uncertain of what numerical routine to use for the integration?

Comment: I need to express expectation as an integral with certain limits.

Comment: It's just $\int_{-\infty}^\infty G(x) f_r(x) dx$, which reduces to $\int_{\frac{d \sqrt{3}}{2}}^{2d} G(x) f_r(x) dx$ because of the structure of $f_r$. You could further subdivide into the three pieces of $f_r$ if you wanted (which, for various reasons, is probably a good idea computationally speaking).

Comment: shit! you mean that it can not be expressed in a tractable form because of uncertainty on $\beta$. SAD FACE! I appreciate that my friend. although I;m going to deal with aftermath of this shock. SOB! SOB!

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "tractable". Perhaps "integrable in closed form"? That seems rather hopeless already with $x \cos^{-1}(C/x)$ along with the exponential involving the arctangent. This is without even getting into the issue of $\beta$...

Comment: with "tractable" I mean just expressing integral like $\int_{d}^{R_{th1}} \frac{A}{r^v} \frac{4x}{\sqrt{3}d^2}\cos^{-1}(\frac{d\sqrt3}{2x})dr$ and so on. then evaluating integral numerically.